# How useful is the study of entanglement entropy to quantum computing?

Tags: quantum-computer, topological-order, entanglement-entropy

My question is somewhat conceptual: how, exactly, can we get closer to building a quantum computer by studying entanglement entropy? I've been reading all about the AdS/CFT correspondence and watching talks at the entanglement seminar at KITP over the last few weeks, and I see how the study of entanglement can lead to a better understanding of quantum information, many-body systems, and quantum phase transitions. However, how, explicitly, can it help us experimentally realize some kind of quantum computer or topological quantum computer?

EDIT: In response to some comments, I guess I am specifically wondering about the connection between AdS/CFT, and how studying the connection between entanglement entropy and AdS black holes could lead to practical applications in quantum computing.

Comment: This is another one of those opinion based questions, so I can only give you my opinion: the construction of a reliable and useful quantum computer falls pretty squarely into applied solid state physics or quantum optics. AdS/CFT deals with a level of physical reality that is currently completely inaccessible to experimentalists, so there is little one can learn about practical building materials (quantum dots, isolated atoms etc.), but the general lessons learned might be applicable to design of quantum computing algorithms, and if the field lacks one thing more than hardware, it's software.

Comment: Entanglement is at the heart of quantum mechanics. Are you asking how studying quantum mechanics will bring us closer to realizing a quantum computer? Otherwise, it might help if you could make your question more concrete.  (E.g., are you asking about AdS/CFT, or the entanglement theory pursued in quantum information, or the precise concept of entanglement *entropy*?)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Okay--I fixed my question so that it would be more specific. I am most concerned about AdS/CFT and its practical applications to quantum computing, both to algorithms and hardware.

Comment: @CuriousOne That clears up my question the hardware. However, how can an AdS/CFT description of entanglement entropy help us develop quantum computing algorithms? I've seen articles that apply AdS/CFT to quantum gravity and string theory, but I'm having a hard time finding anything that talks about applications of an AdS/CFT study of entanglement entropy to quantum algorithms.

Comment: @JoshuahHeath Ok, so why would you think that thinking about entanglement entropy in AdS/CFT would be useful for quantum computing?  I don't think that is the intention behind AdS/CFT.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I have heard from different sources that entanglement entropy (EE) is important for quantum computing--that it, that EE is a measure of the maximal amount of information which can be stored in a system, and EE for Cherns-Simon gauge theories is important for topological quantum computation. I also know that, from the AdS/CFT correspondence, that there is an area law of entanglement entropy in conformal field theory that makes it analogous to a black hole in AdS. Therefore, I was wondering how an AdS description of EE would help us build a topological quantum computer.

Comment: Fluid dynamics is an important part of studying astrophysics; the intergalactic medium, star formation and evolution, describing the matter-energy content of the universe. Fluid dynamics is also of extreme importance to developing aircraft. So your question is similar to asking how the cosmological/astrophysical description and application of fluid dynamics would help us build a better airplane. It's possible the experience from using it in astrophysics might help us when designing an airplane, but there's not really much of a connection between the two topics

Comment: @JoshuahHeath Is there a reason you keep asking about entanglement *entropy*?  There is no doubt that studying entanglement is important for quantum computation and topological order.  Entanglement *entropy* is a measure of entanglement which is relates to a specific scenario -- asymptotic conversion of many copies -- which seems to have little relevance be itself for quantum computing or topological order.  So I would guess that anything one could learn from EE about these problems one can also learn from studying a range of other measures/properties of entanglement.